# how to add Text Field to array and then use it as loop

Tags: java

I need help with this i need to use text field as array list and use it as loop

```
JtextField[] mytexts = new JtextField [TextAD1,TextAD2,TextAD3]
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
          System.out.println(mytext.gettext() +" - " + i);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with [How to use arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is really coming down to basic Java - Your problem is, you need to create an array and iterate over it's contents.  I'd suggest starting with [How to use arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
JTextField[] mytexts = new JTextField[]{new JTextField("text 1"), new JTextField("Text 2"), new JTextField("Text 3")};
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    JTextField field = mytexts[i];
    System.out.println(field.getText() + " - " + i);
}
```

If you don't care about the index, you should also have a look at the [enhanced for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

```
for (JTextField field : mytexts) {
    System.out.println(field.getText());
}
```

Comment: is there a way i can use instead of 'TextField("text 1"), new JTextField("Text 2"), new JTextField("Text 3")'

Comment: You can use what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
JTextField txt1 = new JTextField("Text1");
JTextField txt2 = new JTextField("Text2");
JTextField[] mytexts = new JTextField[]{txt1,txt2};

for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
   String currentText = mytexts[i].getText();
   System.out.println(currentText +" - " + i);
}
```